# How to export Decision Tree model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I want to export my Decision Tree model to use with another python file.
When I finished train model then I want to export that model.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it and load it using module `pickle`, here are the [docs from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).